Expected value of false positive rate for Rabin-Miller
I would like to know how confident to be about the result of a Rabin-Miller is_prime() test for a given k.
When running tests with $k=10$ and randomly chosen bases, I can't find any false positives in a billion trials.  The actual exception rate seems much better than $4^{−k}$.  Can the actual false positive probability be quantified?
In this MathExchange answer, the respondent says:

Thus if you independently randomly choose  distinct bases mod ,
then each will pass Miller's test with probability bounded above by
$1/4$. This is where the $1/4^$ comes from.
I'll note that typically, the number is actually much less than $1/4$.

If "the number is actually much less than $1/4$", how much less on average?

BTW: If you want to see the result of a single test you can use:
miller_rabin(p,1) with p being the number you want to test, you can adjust the '1' to increase the number of random bases you want to test.

I don't know which is_prime() you are referring to but it highly likely that multiple Miller-Rabin test are performed for random bases. For example I use is_prime() on Genuis calculator and it uses 40 bases.
The chance of finding a false positive becomes $(1/4)^{40}$ and is astronomically small.
Edit (see comment): The fraction is only 1/4 for pseudo primes, pseudo primes are only pseudo primes for 25% of the bases maximal. For all other number the percentage (and fraction) is smaller.

And even the $\frac14$ itself is typically rather larger than in practice.

@GregMartin That is the core of the question. In practice, what is the fraction that is rather larger than $\frac{1}{4}$?

@Raymond Hettinger: The comment reads 1/4 itself is typically rather larger so this means the fraction is smaller than 1/4. I also edited my answer to clarify this.
